# Applying rule on file name with checkstyle?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle via the Eclipse plugin [Eclipse-cs](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/).

I want to force my HTML files to use a specific pattern for the name. I want my all HTML files to use this convention for naming:

`test-checkStyle-beginner.html`

Others should display a warning.

I could not find anything under Eclipse-cs to enforce this convention. Is it achievable with Eclipse-cs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Checkstyle can't do that out-of-the-box. You will have to [write a custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html#Writing_FileSetChecks). In your case, this check is really simple. Just see if the given file is an HTML file, then check your naming convention.